# Android WebView load from internal storage | Android 11 | Android R

Tags: android

Actually my requirement is I want to load dynamic files into WebPage like image. video, audio etc.., it's either from asset or apps own files directory, that's not a problem.

I tried using following two ways.

**Way 1**

Here is my html file is in assets folder, and I have `123.jpg` in both assets folder and also internal folder,

Home.html,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Page Title</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Image testing</h1>
      <p>Relative Path</p>
      <img src="123.jpg" alt="Italian Trulli" width="100%">
      <p>From Files Directory</p>
      <img src="file:////data/user/0/com.guna.testapplication/files/123.jpg" alt="Italian Trulli" width="100%">
   </body>
</html>
```

And I am loading it into webview like

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Home.html")
```

**And here is my output for 29,**

[image]

Look, both from Asset and files directory loaded as expected.

**And here is for 30,**

[image]

Here only from asset directory loaded. And files directory not loaded.

**Way 2**

Here I'm loading both html and image from internal storage.

Home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Page Title</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Image testing</h1>
      <img src="123.jpg" alt="Italian Trulli" width="100%">
   </body>
</html>
```

And I'm loading webview like this,

```
webView.loadUrl("file:////data/user/0/com.guna.testapplication/files/Home.html")
```

If my `compileSdkVersion 29` and also `targetSdkVersion 29` this works well,

**Output for 29**

[image]

If I change SdkVersion like `compileSdkVersion 30` and also `targetSdkVersion 30` this gives me access denied error,

**Output on 30**

[image]

**Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221315/discussion-on-question-by-gunaseelan-android-webview-load-html-from-internal-sto).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Found the Answer,

From [setAllowFileAccess](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings#setAllowFileAccess(boolean)) we have to explicitly set it to `true` when we are targeting [Build.VERSION_CODES.R](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES#R), otherwise it wont allow you to load `file:// URLs`.

So the solution is

```
webView.settings.allowFileAccess = true
```

In Java,

```
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
```

This works as expected for both scenario.

Comment: Indeed. Thank you for sharing knowledge. In Java: `webView1.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true); `

Comment: Omg, I spent a whole day fighting exactly this issue with Android 11. Documentation is sooo useless, why? it just bugs my mind.

Comment: Same here.... Thank you so much!

Comment: where can I add the `webView.settings.allowFileAccess = true` ?